# Time Complexity of Algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, time-complexity, code-complexity

Here is my code for the sorting the list in ascending order. I have used function within the function. Now I want to calculate the Time complexity of this function. From my side I have calculate that the function "unite" is called every time when function "sort" complete its loop. So two functions are used every time in this function. So I have concluded that the Complexity of this function is O(nlog(n)).
I am new to this chapter. So I want to know how to calculate this type of complexity. The answer above is just my approximation. And neither I know the real answer nor I have any solution or hints. So please describe your answer whenever you give.
Thanks.
Here is my code.

```
def sort(lst):
    def unite(l1, l2):
        if len(l1) == 0:
            return l2
        elif len(l2) == 0:
            return l1
        elif l1[0] < l2[0]:
            return [l1[0]] + unite(l1[1:], l2)
        else:
            return [l2[0]] + unite(l1, l2[1:])

    if len(lst) == 0 or len(lst) == 1:
        return lst
    else:
        front = sort(lst[:len(lst)/2])
        back = sort(lst[len(lst)/2:])

        L = lst[:]  # the next 3 questions below refer to this line
        return unite(front, back)
```

Comment: Whence cometh `sort4`?

Comment: Actually, it's at least O(n^2) because `unite` makes O(n^2) copies for inputs of size n1 + n2 = n. (And O(n log n) is not an approximation of that in any sense of the word.)

Comment: Oh but I have see couple of examples which have function calls with in the function. And they have the complexity of O(log(n)).

Comment: Just because you have function calls in a function doesn't mean that they're the same complexity as your examples. Runtime is based on what the functions do, not where they're constructed. There is a way to write your `unite` function that will allow it to run in `O(n)`, but you didn't do that.

Comment: You might benefit from reading some of the other questions (especially the high-voted ones) with the tags `time-complexity` and/or `big-o`.

Comment: My favourite source on solving the general problem is the highest-voted answer to [Big O, how do you calculate/approximate it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255/big-o-how-do-you-calculate-approximate-it).

Answer (score 1):

First step is to note that the real work is being done in the `unite` step of your code, which does `n^2` work because you're creating new lists every time.

So you can actually write a quick recurrence for the amount of work your function is doing:

```
W(n) = 2W(n/2) + n^2
```

because you're recursing twice on lists that are of length `n/2` and doing `n^2` work to rejoin them.

Now, consider a recursion tree - at a certain level of the tree (call it level `i`), you're doing `2^i * (n/2^i)^2` work. That's about `O(n^2)` work at each level, and there's `log(n)` levels, so you're doing `O(n^2log(n))` work.

However, there is a way to write your `unite` function so it runs much faster, in `O(n)` time. In that case, you'd be doing (by a similar analysis as above) `O(nlog(n))` work.

Comment: No. n^2 is not the correct answer.
Still I do not have any answer.

Answer (score 0):

The time for **sort** to execute on an n-element vector is T(n).

```
T(n) =  2 T(n/2) + n

     =  2 [2 T(n/4) + n/2] + n

     =  4 T(n/4) + 2n

     = 4 [2 T(n/8) + n/4] + 2n

     = 8 T(n/8) + 3n
     ........

     = 2k T(n/2k) + k n

     = 2log2 n T(1) + (log2n) n   because T(1)=O(1) 

     = n + n log2 n    

     = O(n log n)
```

There is an easy way to remember the complexity for sort solution recursive function. T(selection sort) = O(n^2), and T(merge sort) = O(nlogn). Obviously, your code is merge sort type.

Answer (score 0):

Time Complexity (not space complexity) of above code is `O(nlog(n))`.

There are `n` elements in the list at start and we recursively divide that list in `n/2` elements every time into `front` and `back` which makes it `O(log(n))` steps.
Now, for each of `O(log(n))` steps we iterate over each element in `l1` and `l2` in `unite` function only once which makes complexity of `unite` function `O(n)`.

Hence, for `O(log(n))` divisions and `O(n)` unite steps makes this algorithm `O(nlog(n))` of time complexity.

Other answers are discussing about space complexity of `unite` function which is `O(n^2)`, but question title clearly asks about time complexity and not about space complexity.